# Returning all columns from a SQL Server stored procedure using recursive WITH statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an `Entity` table that organized as a tree structure where `Entity.EntityParent` is the `Entity.EntityID` of an entity's parent.

I have a stored procedure that will return all of the child entities for an `EntityID`.

Rather than listing all of the columns to be selected, as it is set up below, I would like to be able to return all of the columns (like when preforming a select * operation) so that if columns in the table are added in the future, I don't have to manually update the stored procedure.

This is the working query I am currently using.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pEntityChildren]
@Parent int
 AS
 BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

 WITH EntityChildren (EntityID, EntityParent, EntityName, EntityEmail, ... , level)
 AS
 (
      SELECT EntityID, EntityParent, EntityName, EntityEmail, ... , 0 as level from Entity as e where EntityParent = @Parent
      UNION ALL
      SELECT e2.EntityID, e2.EntityParent, e2.EntityName, e2.EntityEmail, ... , level +1 from Entity as e2 INNER JOIN EntityChildren on e2.EntityParent = EntityChildren.EntityID
 )
 select * from EntityChildren
 END
```

T:;DR, I have a working stored procedure, and want to alter it so that it will return all columns.

Additional note: I will be using this as a Function Import with an Entity Framework model that will be mapping the query results to `Entity`.

Comment: I don't think that this can be done, because you need to keep modifying one of the columns(`level`) throughout your recursive queries.  AFAIK, there's no way to keep the same column set and modify one of them without naming all of the columns.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.

Comment: Unless you have a PIA dba that asks too many irrelevant questions, I suggest that you do it properly and enumerate the columns. I know many app developers try their best to circumvent the dba, where the best solution is to get him fired, instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can return all column names as comma separated string

```
declare @colNames varchar(max)
select @colNames=COALESCE(@colNames+',','')+COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME='Entity'
```

Then use dynamic sql to build your query .
for eg

```
Declare @strQry varchar(max)

Set @strQry = 'Select ' + @colNames + ' From Entity'

Exec (@strQry)
```

does a `Select * from Entity`. So any change in table definition gets automatically reflected